# Continue executing a chained RxJava observable on error, stop executing only when specific condition is met

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

How to continue executing a Retrofit network call observable that takes in as items as input obtained from another observable that is converted to `flatMapIterable` even if an error was encountered and stop iterating only if I encounter a specific HTTP status code?

I have a list of `JSON` requests saved in shared preferences, that I need to send one by one using Retrofit, only stopping whenever I get a certain HTTP status code. If I get other exceptions, I just need to continue sending the next items in the requests list. Whenever a request receives a successful response, I remove that particular request from my request list. If other requests have encountered errors, they do not get removed from the list and I save them again to the shared preferences.

So far, I do this inside a `ViewModel` object. First, I fetch these requests via a method (`paramRepository.getSavedOfflineRequest()`) that returns an RxJava `Observable<List<Request>>`. I want to iterate through all the requests so that I can send the items as inputs to `apiService.sale`, which is my Retrofit call, so I use `flatMapIterable`. If the request is successful, I remove the request and save a `Transaction` object to DB.

```
public LiveData<UploadStatus> startUploading() {
    MutableLiveData<UploadStatus> uploadStatus = new MutableLiveData<>();
    compositeDisposable.add(paramRepository.getSavedOfflineRequest()
        .doOnComplete(() -> uploadStatus.setValue(UploadStatus.NO_ITEMS))
        .flatMapIterable( requests -> requests)
        .flatMapCompletable(request -> apiService.sale(saleUrl, BuildConfig.ApiKey,request)
            .doOnSuccess(response -> {
                requestList.remove(request);
                transactions.add(createTransaction(request, response));
            }).ignoreElement()
         )
        .andThen(saveUploadedToDb(transactions))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(() -> uploadStatus.setValue(UploadStatus.SUCCESS),
            error -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "error");
                if (error instanceof HttpException) {
                    HttpException httpException = (HttpException) error;
                    int statusCode = httpException.code();
                    if (statusCode == 401) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "logged out");
                        uploadStatus.setValue(UploadStatus.LOGGED_OUT);
                    }
                } else {
                    uploadStatus.setValue(UploadStatus.FAIL);
                }
            }));

    return uploadStatus;
}
```

I expect that if if I get other errors/exceptions, I just continue making calls using `apiService.sale` with the next `Request` item. But I noticed that the whole chain stops when just one error is encountered, thus the other `Requests` have not been sent.

I have tried `onErrorResumeNext`, but it expects a return of another kind of `Exception`, which is totally different from what I want (do nothing for other Exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the observable to return UploadStatus and map the response.

E.g.

```
    .map { response ->
        switch(response.code()) {
            case 200:
                return UploadStatus.SUCCESS;
            case 401:
                return UploadStatus.LOGGED_OUT;
            default:
                return UploadStatus.FAIL;
        }
     }
```

In the case of an exception, you can use `onErrorReturn` to return UploadStatus.FAIL/ERROR. This won't terminate the stream.

```
    .onErrorReturn { UploadStatus.FAIL }
```

Comment: I refactored my code to be similar to the answer for this post describing a situation very similar to mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52617904/rxjava-upstream-never-completes-when-error-is-swallowed?rq=1